# Why this is O(1) (the big oh)??

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, analytic-number-theory

How can I prove that this sum

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\log(n)}{n(n-1)}=O(1) $$

that means that is bounded or is convergent? how can i prove it?

Comment: When all the terms are positive, "bounded" and "convergent" mean the same thing

Comment: Did you look at the definition of $O(\ )$? (Which, by the way, is **incorrectly** used in your question... What is your source for this?)

Comment: In this case $O(1)$ simply means the sum is bounded. However, since this is a convergent sequence (by the integral test), this is enough to prove that it is bounded.

Comment: that appears in a proof ion the book introduction to analytic number theory by tom apostol

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a non-sensical usage of $O(\cdot)$. But it could mean that

$$\sum_{n=2}^{N}\frac{\log(n)}{n(n-1)}=O(1)\tag{1}$$

Big $O$ is about a function, and the left side of your expression is not a function of any variable, it is either a value or undefined.

Since all summands here are positive, (1) is equivalent to saying the series converges.

To prove this is convergent, you might note that:

$$\frac{\log n}{n(n-1)}=\frac{\log(n)}{n-1}-\frac{\log(n)}{n}$$

So:

$$\sum_{n=2}^{N}\frac{\log(n)}{n(n-1)}=\frac{\log 2}{1}-\frac{\log(N)}{N}+\sum_{n=2}^{N-1} \frac{\log(n+1)-\log(n)}{n}$$

But $$0<\log(n+1)-\log(n)=\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)<\frac{1}n$$

So $0<\frac{\log(n+1)-\log(n)}{n}<\frac{1}{n^2}$, and since $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges, and $\log(2)-\frac{\log(N)}{N}=O(1)$, you get your result.

Comment: (+1) You might want to shorten referring to known results on *Bertrand's series* .

Answer (score 2):

By comparison with the $p$-series $\sum_n \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$ *(for instance -- any constant $1<p<2$ will work here)*, we have that the series you are considering converges.

Thus, it is both convergent and bounded.

However, writing $O(1)$ here is *(at least as far as I can tell)* a strange notation, and an abuse of the asymptotic $O(\cdot)$ notation: there is not asymptotics at play here (no variable going to infinity; no free variable at all, for that matter.)

Comment: i have revised my notes and yes, $O(1)$ means that the series is bounded

Comment: I am not questioning your good faith. If that's what your notes write, I am questioning them. Again, asymptotics are taken with regard to a variable (or more), around a specific point. Here, you have no variable on the LHS.

Comment: For instance, writing $\sum_{n=2}^N \frac{\log n}{n(n-1)} =O(1)$ (as $N$ goes to infinity) would make sense. Do you see the difference?

Comment: @ClementC. It is not that unusual to write $O(1)$ for a constant if all we care about is that the constant exists (and wish to draw attention to its finiteness).  I agree it would be an odd choice to state it as a final result, but seems reasonable to use as an intermediate result in a longer computation.

Comment: @ErickWong I see your point, but let's agree to disagree. I'd write $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\log n}{n(n-1)} < \infty$, which conveys the same meaning, uses fewer characters, and is standard and formally correct. I've seen enough uses of asymptotic notations in my field either wrong, somewhat teeth-cringing,  or not fully specified, to avoid that sort of things whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

In general, $O(1)$ means it's bounded.  Since in this case the terms are positive, that implies it is convergent.  You can use Limit Comparison Test with $\sum n^{-p}$ where $1 < p < 2$.